# What is the influence of outliers in discriminant analysis?

Tags: normal-distribution, outliers, discriminant-analysis

In discriminant analysis like a Canonical Regression Analysis, the outliers tend to skew the results of the analysis, but nowhere can I find "how much" the outliers influences the analysis.
What I'd like to know is if there is if the outlier's influence is measurable on the analysis regarding their number and their value in relationship with the sample size and distribution.

Comment: In the two group problem, the various diagnostics from linear regression are appropriate. In theory, sure, there must be such a measure of the influence of observations for three or more groups. The terms to search for are "influence" (for measures of the impact that an individual observation has on the results) or "robust" for variants of LDA that are not greatly influented by observations.

Comment: The influence is the same as in ANOVA/MANOVA (and is potentially severe). Diagnostics is similar.